# Prove that only multiples of $4$ (except $4$) and odd numbers can be made from the difference of two squares

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-writing

I need to be able to prove that every odd number (except $1$) and every multiple of $4$ (except $4$) can be written as a difference of two squares.

EDIT: Only Positive integers are allowed.

Comment: Hint : remember that $x^2 - y^2 = (x+y)\cdot(x-y)$

Comment: I'm aware of that struggling to find a formal proof for the question though

Comment: Well, equate $x^2 - y^2$ to $4k$ or $2k+1$ and find suitable values for $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$2n+1=(n+1)^2-n^2$$ and $$4n=(n+1)^2-(n-1)^2$$

To show that numbers of the form $4n+2=2(2n+1)$ is not expressible in the form $x^2-y^2,$ observe that both $x,y$ has to be the same parity and use it to derive a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**Pointers:**

- Note that odd numbers can be produced by subtracting consecutive squares.
- Note that multiples of $4$ can be produced by taking squares with a difference of $2$.
- So, why can’t we express the other numbers as a difference of squares?